# AWS Update Cloudfront Domain Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to update the Origins_Item specifically the Domain Name in a CloudFront Distribution using the Update-CFDistribution.

After consulting the AWS Powershell Reference here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html

This is the code I am trying to use.

```
$CloudFront = $(Get-CFDistribution -Id abc123def).DistributionConfig.Origins.Items
$CloudFront.DomainName = "test.example.amazonaws.com"
Update-CFDistribution -Origins_Item $CloudFront -Id abc123def
```

But I am encountering the following error:

```
The property 'DomainName' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

I am new to both powershell and AWS so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that the path to DomainNames property isn't correct. Can you please refer to the payload provided in this question ?
[AWS cli query to get to cloudfront "Domain Name" with specific origin name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323275/aws-cli-query-to-get-to-cloudfront-domain-name-with-specific-origin-name)

Comment: I have updated my statement from

`$CloudFront = $(Get-CFDistribution -Id abc123def).DistributionConfig.Origins.Items`

to 

`$CFDomain = $(Get-CFDistributionConfig -Id abc123def).Origins.Items`

and I am still seeing the same error message.

I used this link as well to update my command. In this link you can see the DomainName I am trying to update is under Items which is under Origins which is under DistributionConfig.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094615/aws-cli-create-cloudfront-distribution-distribution-config)